# VS Code cannot open UNC path files because of Allowed UNCHosts case sensitivity

Tags: visual-studio-code

Known issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182277

I have added the COMPUTERNAME to the allowed list.
[image]

After which I continue to receive this message. It also appears after I have rebooted the machine and started VS Code again.
[image]

```
PS C:\> code --version
1.78.2
b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435
x64
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following to your `settings.json` file:

```
"security.allowedUNCHosts": ["[UNC path]", "wsl.localhost", "wsl$"]
```

Replace [UNC path] with the server path i.e. `\\server-a\users\profile` would go in the `settings.json` file like:

```
"security.allowedUNCHosts": ["server-a", "wsl.localhost", "wsl$"]
```

The `settings.json` file can be found in `%APPDATA% --> Code\User` folder
or for VSCode Portable in the Data\user-data\User folder. Make sure to restart all instances of VSCode after changing this setting.

Alternatively, in VSCode you can use ctrl + , and search for Allowed UNCHosts, then add wsl$, wsl.localhost, and [UNC path name] i.e. server-a.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to add the settings through the VSCode UI (`Open Settings (UI)`), but the setting wasn't found in settings.json and wasn't applied. Writing it manually in settings.json worked.

Answer (score 0):

in windows explorer, open you WSL host and map it (right click on WSL host and choose map network drive) and choose any drive letter (i.e Z),

in vs code: after the mapping is done, you can start to use it and add your WSL folder to your workspace in your vs code like ussual

Comment: The goal is to live without drive letters. Drive letters will not scale; there are a limited (small) amount available. With PowerShell a drive "name" can be created with `New-PSDrive`. I have not tested use of these with VS Code. The bug is said to be in the next monthly VS Code update.

Comment: Unacceptable answer.  There is no valid reason to force people into using drive letters.